# Applying a calculation to a cell's value when another cell = "TRUE"

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I'm doing some coursework to complete an advanced spreadsheet.

I'm creating a spreadsheet for a retailer which sells electronic equipment. I have multiple sheets set up with tables of customer details, product details (with stock and re-order functions), an "order processing screen" and an "order history screen". On this order processing screen the user is able to select their name from a list, select their desired product from a list, and click a button which registers their order.

When the user clicks to register their order, it fully appears in the order history sheet, and isn't replaced after every click. I'm stuck on how to decrease the stock by 1 every time that product is bought.

My current solution is that when an order appears on the order history list (which is after the macro is clicked and the details are pulled from the order processing screen and put onto the order history list), the product name is compared against all the product names in the product list table, and when it reaches a match it displays "TRUE". Something like:

```
IF <TRUE/FALSE cell> = "TRUE"
-1 from <stock number cell>
```

When a new order comes in, the formula checks its name, and on the product list sheet, it finds its stock number and reduces it by 1. I  can't figure out how to reduce the figure by 1 when my TRUE/FALSE row displays TRUE.

EDIT: Here are some pictures of the situation to accompany it:

[Product List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMb9L.png)

[Order purchase list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk6cx.png)

Comment: Look at something like offset('prods'!$a$1,match(prod,prod col,0),col num of stock).value = offset('prods'!$a$1,match(prod,prod col,0),col num of stock).value-1

Comment: A better solution maybe to have a start, physical stock, then a floating stock of this value minus the orders? Just as a formula

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the `Worksheet_Change` event for the sheet that contains the cells indicating the product has changed. Your function looks at the list of products for TRUE/FALSE then decrements the product count by one. (Don't forget to reset the flag back to FALSE!)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '--- example assumes flag indicating product has changed in column B, rows 2-100
    '    and the product count is on the same row as the flag in column G
    Dim productChangeFlag As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Target.Parent
    If Intersect(Target, ws.Range("B2:B100")) Is Nothing Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each productChangeFlag In Target
        If WorksheetFunction.IsLogical(productChangeFlag) And productChangeFlag = True Then
            ws.Cells(productChangeFlag.Row, 7).Value = ws.Cells(productChangeFlag.Row, 7).Value - 1
            ws.Cells(productChangeFlag.Row, productChangeFlag.Column).Value = False
        End If
    Next productChangeFlag
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```